# Unhide the selected cells' 'tick' in a collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionView` of images and I want to show when multiple of these cells are selected.

I use a simple `cell.myUIImage.isHidden = false` but nothing seems to work.

Multiple select is enabled in the **Interface Builder** and is set in `viewDidLoad()`, this is what I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myUIImage: UIImageView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoItemView", for: indexPath) as! PhotoFeed

    cell.myUIImage.isHidden = false
    print ("cell was selected at:", indexPath.item)

    photoCollection.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Calling `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRow` cannot work. Where is the  cell returned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can not access `UICollectionViewCell` with `dequeueReusableCell` other than `cellForItemAt indexPath` method.

To access cell in `didSelectItemAt indexPath` use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let collectionCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PhotoFeed {
        collectionCell.myUIImage.isHidden = false
        print ("cell was selected at:", indexPath.item)
        photoCollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

> But again `photoCollection.reloadData()` will reload the cell and `myUIImage` will be hidden again.
>
> So you need to maintain the selected indexes and show/hide in `cellForItemAt indexPath`. With the help of `selectedIndexes` you can have the functionality like show image on selection and hide image on select again.

**You should have an array of `selectedIndexes`. Say**

```
var selectedIndexes = [IndexPath]()
```

**Add in `didSelectItemAt indexPath`, Update method as:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath) {
        if let index = selectedIndexes.index(of: indexPath) {
            selectedIndexes.remove(at: index)
        }
    } else {
        selectedIndexes.append(indexPath)
    }
    photoCollection.reloadData()
}
```

**In `cellForItemAt indexPath`:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {\
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoItemView", for: indexPath) as? PhotoFeed  else {
        fatalError("cell not found")
    }
    if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.myUIImage.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.myUIImage.isHidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and I've learnt something new! I did have to put the .reloadData() back in there though, so you might want to update the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should create @IBOutlet for myUIImage in collectionviewcell:

```
class PhotoFeed: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myUIImage: UIImageView!

}
```

In ViewController:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoItemView", for: indexPath) as! PhotoFeed

            return cell
        }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PhotoFeed

                cell.myUIImage.isHidden = !cell.myUIImage.isHidden

}
```